# Is it possible to create a fully self-contained Python package?

Tags: python, pip, ansible

### The question

Ansible is a python moduel, installable via pip. It relies on several dependencies, also pip modules. Is it possible to "roll up" all of those dependencies and Ansible itself into some sort of a single package, that can be installed offline, without root? It's highly preferable to not need pip for the install, although it will be available for package creation.

### Extra background

I'm trying to install Ansible on one of our servers. The server does not have access to the internet, there is no root access. Pip is not installed, but Python is. It is possible to get pip installed there, but might be complicated. The only way to get anything on the server is via an internal tar.gz package sharing solution.

I've tried fiddling around with rpm, saving dependencies, but the absence of root access put an end to that.

Comment: can you use virtual_env?

Comment: Sure, you just have to copy all the dependencies over and make sure everything is in the right palce

Comment: @njzk2 yes, please write up an answer on that, but a simpler approach would be preferable

Comment: @IanAuld does that basically mean I have to write a combined installer script for all of the dependencies?

Comment: @IanAuld I imagine you'd have to grab the module and dependencies and then run setup.py for each of them, yes?

Comment: That's one way you could do it.

Comment: I usually start a project by setting up a virtual env, pip installing stuff that I need, then pip freezing the dependency list in a requirements file. then in the install process, you simply need to pip install from the requirements file. similar to what is described here: http://www.enigmeta.com/2012/08/16/starting-flask/

Comment: python -m pip install .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use pip on an internet-connected machine to download all the deps to a local dir with `--download and -r requirements.txt`, then drop that dir on the disconnected machine with pip installed, and install using `--no-index and --find-links=(archive dir)`.

See https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fast-local-installs